# Changing Port Number on BitNami WAMP

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, bitnami

I've installed the BitNami WAMP server and had to change the port number.  I have changed the port number by changing "Listen" in httpd.conf.  I am able to access the web server, however the PHPMyAdmin stopped working.  Is there another place where I need to change anything else?

Comment: Cannot help with Bitnami config, but until someone does you will have to add the new port number to the url manually like this `localhost:8080/phpmyadmin`

Comment: RiggsFolly, that is how I'm trying to access it.  http://localhost:8080 gives me the BitNami welcome screen, but localhost:8080/phpmyadmin doesn't work.  All was good before I changed the port number, so I'm guessing there is another config file that I'm missing for re-routing to the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing but could it be the "httpd-vhosts.conf" file in the ../apps/phpmyadmin/conf subdirectory of your Bitnami stack main directory?

Comment: If not there, check bitnami.conf . htaccess rewrites weren't working for me until i changed the ports in this file